# How to prevent users from logging in via ssh manually?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a script that connects to a remote server with the key. However I don't want people to log in to the server by typing the ssh command, but the script should work.

**Edit** : The script initiates a remote port forward. It contains the normal ssh -R command with all required parameter, and also set up a pseudo terminal with -t starting a script in the remote server also passing some variables. The script in remote server checks the variable sent via -t and decides whether to accept the port forward connection or just close the ssh connection.

Comment: And what are people doing on the remote server? Shell access? Or running a specific program?

Comment: The script they run is to set up remote port forward. Thats why i dont want them to login to server and execute any sort of commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want users to only be able to use port forwarding, you should be setting up restrictions on the server.

Like discussed [here on Ubuntu Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding):

```
Match Group some-group
   #AllowTcpForwarding yes
   X11Forwarding no
   PermitTunnel no
   GatewayPorts no
   AllowAgentForwarding no
   PermitOpen localhost:62222
   ForceCommand echo 'This account can only be used for port forwarding'
```

Users in the UNIX group `some-group` will then not be able to do anything but using port forwarding to `localhost:62222`. `ssh` must be invoked with `-N` (“Do  not execute a remote command.”) because otherwise `ForceCommand` will take effect and kill the connection.

If you want remote port forwarding, you need to use `PermitListen` instead of `PermitOpen` and an appropriate `GatewayPorts` option.

Comment: localhost:62222? Is it for only one port? cause there are many people using it and the script asks "Enter the local port to be forwarded" and continues. So now what?

Comment: You don’t need to restrict the ports if you don’t want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps replace the script by a binary that decrypts a key on the fly. That would make it harder (but not impossible) to capture the key for other purposes.

If there is only one thing to run on the server, you can try to make that a script that is defined as their login shell.

But IMHO it is safer to write a small web server that runs the actions on the server, with the local script doing `curl` calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to restrict the amount of access that the ssh user you are using to connect has. So even if they do connect, they can't do anything.  You could do this by creating a new user and setting up correct permissions for just this connection. Additionally you could set up a virutal-environment on your server for that user that is isolated from the rest of your server. If you don't set up a virtual environemnt, you would need to do a security audit on your files to make sure there aren't any 'everybody' permissions on files/directories that would be available to this user.

Comment: I did edit /etc/passwd to set the user's login shell to rbash. However, people can still type command (although it won't work) and get some errors like command not found or something like that.

Comment: So there is a thing called chroot jail,
https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/
and apparmor, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor which can give you some additional power in locking down ssh connections.